# Joystick input translates wrong

Tags: windows-10, game-controller, joystick

I have a problem with my trusty old Saitek Cyborg Evo. A while ago I wanted to play IL2 Sturmovik again. Installed everything, plugged in my Evo and started. Unfortunately, something was wrong. The nose of my plane was pushed down. Took a look into the settings and yes, in neutral position of the stick the game thought I would push the stick forward. In the game the input for the y-axis was at neutral position when I pulled back the stick about 50%.

I thought the stick was broken, which would be ok, this thing is way over 10 years old. But I took a look into the calibration options of Windows, I use Windows 10. There, everything was ok. Neutral position, everything was working fine. I tried the stick in another game (Kerbal Space Program) and the stick was working fine.

So I thought it must be a problem with the game, translating the input wrong.

Then I stumbled over this tool here (http://www.xedocproject.com/joystickcurves.html) and decided to try it. As far as I could see, it emulates virtual game controllers so you can modify the input translation. Wouldn't work for my problem as I found out, but the interesting thing was, that I had the exact same behavior like in the game. The tool has a windows where you can see how your input translates, and there, in neutral position of the stick, the program also thought that I pushed the stick forward. So I thought, there must be more to it.

I hope you could follow me so far. Here are some screenshots of this tool (Joystick Curves), so you can really see what I mean:

**Stick in Neutral Position:**

[image]

**Stick pulled back 100%**

[image]

**Stick pulled back 50%**

[image]

**Stick pushed forward 100%**

[image]

As you can see, the Y-axis just translates wrong here, and I have the exact same behavior in IL2. All other axis are working fine, everywhere, even in IL2.

Like I've said, in other games the stick is working fine. In Windows calibration options it looks like this:

**Stick in Neutral Position:**

[image]

**Stick pulled back 100%**

[image]

**Stick pulled back 50%**

[image]

**Stick pushed forward 100%**

[image]

So the stick itself seems to work fine and the problem doesn't only exist in this one game. Are there different methods how the input of such a device is translated into the computer? So that Windows calibration and KSP uses method 1 and the other tool and IL2 uses the other method? Is there something like this?

I installed the latest Saitek drivers (at least the version for Windows 8, because there is no dedicated driver for Windows 10). The joystick is connected via USB. Seems to make no difference if I use USB2 or 3, no difference in using the front slots of the case or the build in slots of the motherboard.
I have used the stick with this game before, but years ago in another version of the game and on another windows version.

Do you have any idea what could cause the problem and more important: how I can fix it? I really don't want to give up my old stick =)

Comment: Have you done the calibration as described in the article [How to Calibrate Your Gaming Controller in Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/241421/how-to-calibrate-your-gaming-controller-in-windows-10/)?

Comment: Yep, several times and like I've said, in the windows calibration options everything seems to work fine.

Comment: The stick should also be in neutral position when you boot. And have yoiu tried another model stick?

Comment: Stick is in neutral position when booting. I couldn't try another stick, I don't have one. As a reference, I have an old original Playstation 2 Controller which I plugged in via an adapter (USB) This thing works fine, all axes work fine.

Comment: Ok, no one seems to have an idea for my problem.
Could we try to work on that?
Let's talk about how a joystick talks with a computer and get's his input into a games engine? What kind of software does the translation and where could something go wrong in the process?

Comment: It's something to do with your hardware/software configuration. If Saitek drivers are not available for Windows 10, try maybe an older version of the driver, even for Windows 7. What happens if you delete the Saitek software and devices - does Windows understand the device?

Comment: I tried the older versions of the driver. I tried the Windows 8.1 drivers, but I'm not sure if I could try both versions, x64 and x86 or if the installation aborted. Also tried the Windows 7 and I think also the XP drivers. I don't know the results of every driver I tried, I think some of them I couldn't install due to incompatibility, but the problem wasn't fixed with one of them.
I'm not entirely sure whether windows recognizes the joystick without Saitek drivers, have to try that in the evening, but I think he recognized it.

Comment: Hey, sorry, couldn't test it till now. I uninstalled everything I could find which belongs to Saitek, rebootet, plugged in the Joystick, let Windows do it's thing and rebooted once more, just to be sure. Now the stick doesn't work at all in the windows gamecontroller settings. Also I can't do a manual calibration. Windows recognizes the Joystick as a Saitek Cyborg EVO and shows a little picture of the actual stick. In the details windows says a driver is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried the latest and the older drivers for the device and it still does
not work right in Windows 10. Windows 10 without Saitek drivers recognizes the device but does not have a driver for it.

The options I can see are :

1. Wait for Saitek to come up with drivers that will work with Windows 10 (probably will not happen).
2. Install the Windows 8 drivers and mark the game exe with compatibility to Windows 8 (probably won't help but worth trying).
3. Downgrade to Windows 8 (just joking).
4. Forget it and get a new joystick.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I agree, Saitek will not come up with new drivers for this device, it's too old. I already tried those other drivers and some compatibility options, didn't help. Downgrade, not going to happen =) It wouldn't be a problem to get another Joystick, it's just that newer joysticks are either pretty cheap in quality and don't have the feature I already have on my Cyborg. Also I don't really want to spend 200 bucks or more for a devent newer one. Also I don't know if I have the same problem when I'm buying an X52 for example, it's also pretty old right now...

Comment: As you only wish to use it for certain games, another solution would be to use a Windows 8 or 7 virtual machine. It might work there.